# Convert special char to html entity in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
  header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
  $str = "A &lt;Bold&gt;";
  $html = htmlentities($str ,ENT_QUOTES);
  echo $html;
 ?>
```

Htmlentities () use to convert special characters to html am I right? But I am getting a string which I assign to $str. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: `html_entity_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

Decode $html with `html_entity_decode`

```
<?php 
  header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
  $str = "A &lt;Bold&gt;";
   $html = htmlentities($str ,ENT_QUOTES);
  echo html_entity_decode($html);
 ?>
```